# R Group and Sum by Time period and Factor variables

Tags: r

I have posted this question before with a very bad explanation, so I deleted it and try again with this one. I also have updated the example to be more concise.

I have the following toy dataset of Cases with Events. It includes the Case ID, Case Start Date, Event Date, Event Type and Event Value. It contains two cases (C1 & C2) and two Event Types (A & B). In the real data I have 1000's of cases and 100's of events.

```
ID      CaseDate    EventDate       Etype   Value
C1      2017-01-01  2017-01-01      A       1
C1      2017-01-01  2017-01-04      A       2
C1      2017-01-01  2017-01-11      A       3
C1      2017-01-01  2017-01-13      B       1
C1      2017-01-01  2017-01-15      B       2
C1      2017-01-01  2017-02-01      A       5
C1      2017-01-01  2017-02-04      A       6
C2      2017-01-03  2017-02-10      B       3
C2      2017-01-03  2017-02-11      B       1
C2      2017-01-03  2017-02-26      A       1
C2      2017-01-03  2017-02-27      A       1
C2      2017-01-03  2017-02-28      B       4
```

My task is to aggregate (Sum) the Values by *Time Periods of 5 days* **AND** *Event Types*. **The trick is that the 5 day periods are from the specific Case Start Date**. So for C1 it would be from 2017-01-01 to 2017-01-05 (Period 1) & 2017-01-06 to 2017-01-10 (Period 2) and so on.

For C2 it would be from 2017-01-03 to 2017-01-07 (Period 1) & 2017-01-08 to 2017-01-12 (Period 2) and so on.

Ultimately I want to end up with a result set as follows:

```
ID  Period  Etype   Sum
C1  1       A       3
C1  1       B       0
C1  2       A       0
C1  2       B       0
C1  3       A       3
C1  3       B       3
C1  4       A       0
C1  4       B       0
C1  5       A       0
C1  5       B       0
C1  6       A       0
C1  6       B       0
C1  7       A       0
C1  7       B       0
C1  8       A       11
C1  8       B       0
C2  1       A       0
C2  1       B       0
C2  2       A       0
C2  2       B       4
C2  3       A       0
C2  3       B       0
C2  4       A       0
C2  4       B       0
C2  5       A       2
C2  5       B       0
C2  6       A       0
C2  6       B       4
C2  7       A       0
C2  7       B       0
C2  8       A       0
C2  8       B       0
```

I have tried all the answers that I could find, but none fits the bill. I have tried working with the xts package & lubridate as well as dplyr to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `data.table`solution

```
library(data.table)
dt_results<-fread("test2.csv") #just reading the data
dt_results[,c("EventDate","CaseDate"):=list(as.Date(EventDate),as.Date(CaseDate))]
dt_results[,Period:=as.numeric(ceiling((EventDate-CaseDate+1)/5))] #constructing your period variable
dt_results[, sum(Value),by=c("ID","Period", "Etype")] #sum and group
```

Hopefully, I have understood correctly what you want to do... Otherwise let me know where I went wrong...

Comment: Yours are by far the fastest and easiest on the memory. I only added the complete function, in case when I need the 0 Events. Now that I see the solution, it is actually very easy, just didn't snap into place. Tx much!

Answer (score 2):

Note that the output is different because I think your period calculations are incorrect. The largest difference in your sample data is ~60 days which would be 12 five-day periods.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  mutate(CaseDate = ymd(CaseDate),
         EventDate = ymd(EventDate), 
         Period = as.integer(1 + (as.integer(EventDate - CaseDate) %/% 5))) %>%
  group_by(ID, Period, Etype) %>%
  summarize(Sum = sum(Value)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  complete(ID, Period = full_seq(Period, 1), Etype, fill = list(Sum = 0)) %>%
  arrange(ID, Period, Etype) 

#        ID Period  Etype   Sum
#    <fctr>  <dbl> <fctr> <dbl>
# 1      C1      1      A     3
# 2      C1      1      B     0
# 3      C1      2      A     0
# 4      C1      2      B     0
# 5      C1      3      A     3
# 6      C1      3      B     3
# 7      C1      4      A     0
# 8      C1      4      B     0
# 9      C1      5      A     0
# 10     C1      5      B     0
# # ... with 38 more rows
```

Comment: You are right, I did a mistake in my output. Apologies for taking so long to get back. This is working 100%.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a (close-to) solution using `xtabs`, which does not include periods with no entries (which might not be a problem in a larger table of real data)...

```
df2 <- as.data.frame(xtabs(Value~ID+ceiling(as.numeric(EventDate-CaseDate+1)/5)+Etype,df))
names(df2)[2] <- "Period"
names(df2)[4] <- "Sum"
df2 <- df2[order(df2$ID,df2$Period,df2$Etype),]

df2
   ID Period Etype  Sum
1  C1      1     A    3
13 C1      1     B    0
3  C1      3     A    3
15 C1      3     B    3
5  C1      7     A   11
17 C1      7     B    0
7  C1      8     A    0
19 C1      8     B    0
9  C1     11     A    0
21 C1     11     B    0
11 C1     12     A    0
23 C1     12     B    0
2  C2      1     A    0
14 C2      1     B    0
4  C2      3     A    0
16 C2      3     B    0
6  C2      7     A    0
18 C2      7     B    0
8  C2      8     A    0
20 C2      8     B    4
10 C2     11     A    1
22 C2     11     B    0
12 C2     12     A    1
24 C2     12     B    4
```

Comment: Also works 100%, simplest solution and I like to 0 periods as it reduces my output. It runs very slowly tho - my output is ~100M rows